# sorting DDMMYYYY monthly using postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I am writing a query using PostgreSQL to count something but I want to sort the date (DDMMYYYY) properly.

With this following codes,

```
WITH dis_id AS (SELECT 
DISTINCT ON (source_user_id) source_user_id,
  created_at
  FROM public.info_scammers )

SELECT  d.date, count(dis_id.source_user_id)
FROM (SELECT to_char(date_trunc('day',(current_date - offs)), 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS date
  FROM generate_series(0,365,1) AS offs
  ) d  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  dis_id
  ON (d.date = to_char(date_trunc('day',dis_id.created_at),'YYYY-MM-DD'))



GROUP BY d.date
```

The result is

```
Date        |   Count
01-01-2017  |   0

01-02-2017  |   0

01-03-2017  |   0
```

What I want is

```
Date        |   Count
01-01-2017  |   0

02-01-2017  |   0

03-01-2017  |   0
```

I have looked up the existing problems. But most of them do not use PostgreSQL

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Leave `d.date` as type `date` in the inner `SELECT` (don't convert it to `text` with `to_char`), then add `ORDER BY d.date` and do the conversion to `text` in the outer `SELECT`.

Something like:

```
WITH dis_id AS (...)
SELECT to_char(d.date, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), count(...)
FROM (SELECT date_trunc(...) AS date
      FROM ...
     ) d
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ...
GROUP BY to_char(d.date, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
ORDER BY d.date;
```

Comment: Thank you Laurenz Albe. However, when I tried to run the query, the error message appeared as follows.
`function date_trunc(unknown, date, unknown) does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types.
You might need to add explicit type casts.
Position: 195 `

Why does is the function `date_trunc` is not recognized?

Comment: You are trying to use `date_trunc` with three arguments, but there is no such function.